# MySQL query to return information from two tables in database filtered by user input

Tags: php, mysql

The project I'm working on is a bus reservation app and I'm currently stuck on my 'Search.php' file that will query the online mysql server for the date of the trip, the location, the destination, the time scheduled for the trip and the price. The date the user specifies will be retrieved from the 'trip' table and the information on the location of the user, his/ her destination, the various timings the trip will be available on that day as well as the price will be fetched from another table 'bus_route'.

At the moment, I've tried joining the two tables with left join as shown below but to know avail. Any suggestions and corrections will be appreciated.

Search.php

```
    <?php   
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id625053_admin", "12345", "id625053_bookbus");

    $from = $_POST["location"];
    $to = $_POST["destination"];
    $tdate = $_POST["travelDate"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "
    SELECT t.trip_date
         , b.route_from
         , b.route_to
         , b.time
         , b.price 
      FROM trip t 
      LEFT 
      JOIN bus_route b 
        ON t.route_id = b.route_id 
     WHERE route_from = ? 
       AND route_to = ? 
       AND trip_date = ?
       ");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $from, $to, $tdate);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $trip_date, $route_from, $route_to, $time, $price);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        $response["success"] = true;
        $response["trip_date"] = $trip_date;
        $response["route_from"] = $route_from;
        $response["route_to"] = $route_to;
        $response["time"] = $time;
        $response["price"] = $price;
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

[trip and bus route mysql tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZY5Q.png)

Comment: I suspect you might have a problem in the format of your date when querying against the tables.  You need to make sure you are querying using the same date format (default 'YYYY-MM-DD').

Comment: try replace `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $from, $to, $tdate);` to this `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $from, $to, $tdate);`

Comment: @M.Rizzo I tested it by entering hardcoded values like $from = "London", $to = "Manchester", $tdate = "2017-02-05"...but i still get the error "Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt"

Comment: @ntaloventi tried that...no luck...same error "
Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /storage/h2/053/625053/public_html/Search1.php on line 10"

Comment: $stament is became boolean, its your connection not throw error?

Comment: `if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   print_r(mysqli_connect_error());
   exit();
}` add this after $con to check is your connection params are true

Comment: Your LEFT JOIN is really an INNER JOIN

Comment: @ntaloventi no, connection is fine, because when I remove the t.tripdate and the trip table and just run "SELECT route_from, route_to, time, price FROM  bus_route WHERE route_from = ? AND route_to = ?", it gives me my output as: {"success":true,"route_from":"Mombasa","route_to":"Nairobi","time":"21:00:00","price":1500}.

Comment: @Strawberry okay, maybe MySQL JOINs very well, but all I'm trying to do is get the 'route_from', 'route_to', 'time', 'price', 'trip_date' from the two tables that hold the values: trp and bus_route, with the users input being the location they are in, the destination they want to travel to and the date of travel. Please advise on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Presumably, the query works just fine in the MySQL CLI / PHPMyAdmin / Workbench, etc.

Comment: @Strawberry Actually solved the problem, but I can't seem to get all the rows from the tables All i get is just one row of data.

Comment: Hmm, maybe that should be `$response["success"][]` or  something like that?!?